# Xvfb not sending SIGUSR1, breaking xvfb-run

Tags: signals, trap, xvfb

I've been working a knotty problem trying to run headless tests using the xvfb-run script provided with [Xvfb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+package/xvfb).  It works on my own Ubuntu images running in VirtualBox, but on the Ubuntu 15.04 AMI that Atlassian provides for Elastic Bamboo it doesn't.  I've traced the problem down to here:

xvfb-run:

```
...
# Start Xvfb.
MCOOKIE=$(mcookie)
tries=10
while [ $tries -gt 0 ]; do
    tries=$(( $tries - 1 ))
    XAUTHORITY=$AUTHFILE xauth source - << EOF >>"$ERRORFILE" 2>&1
add :$SERVERNUM $XAUTHPROTO $MCOOKIE
EOF
    # handle SIGUSR1 so Xvfb knows to send a signal when it's ready to accept
    # connections
    trap : USR1
    (trap '' USR1; exec Xvfb ":$SERVERNUM" $XVFBARGS $LISTENTCP -auth $AUTHFILE >>"$ERRORFILE" 2>&1) &
    XVFBPID=$!
    wait || :
    if kill -0 $XVFBPID 2>/dev/null; then
        break
    elif [ -n "$AUTONUM" ]; then
        # The display is in use so try another one (if '-a' was specified).
        SERVERNUM=$((SERVERNUM + 1))
        SERVERNUM=$(find_free_servernum)
        continue
    fi
    error "Xvfb failed to start" >&2
    XVFBPID=
    exit 1
done
...
```

The script gets to the "wait" but never gets the expected SIGUSR1 from Xvfb. (If I send a SIGUSR1 manually the script proceeds normally). I updated all the packages to latest-greatest but still no love, and it's weird because I can make it work on other Ubuntu systems.  The xvfb error log ($ERRORFILE) gets created but has nothing at all in it.

Thoughts on root cause, or at least to delve deeper?

Answer (score 3):

Ah, never mind, I finally found the problem - Atlassian had added a Xvfb wrapper script of their own (/usr/local/bin/Xvfb) that was blocking the signal send. For anyone who has this issue in the future, check and see if Xvfb is being executed directly or via a wrapper, and if it's a wrapper it will break xvfb-run.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else running into the same symptoms with other images, without Atlassian's wrapper script:

Using xvfb-run as main (init) process for a container apparently breaks its internal signal handling, also causing `wait` to hang. Solve that by using an init process such as [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini), either by adding it to the container or by using `docker run --init`.